# Test to make sure two functions run concurrently?

Tags: scala, unit-testing, concurrency

Suppose I've got a function `runConcurrently(f1: Int => Int, f2: Int => Int): (Int, Int)` that return results of `f1` and `f2`.

Now I'd like to write a test to make sure that `f1` and `f2` run *concurrently* when `runConcurrently` is invoked. I'd like to make the test deterministic and as efficient as possible.

How would you suggest write the test ?

P.S. I don't want to couple it with any specific test framework or library. The only dependency should be the Scala/Java SDK.

Comment: I don't think it is the right thing to test. You should test that both functions run. Whether implementation chose to run them concurrently or sequentially is irrelevant (and, frankly, beyond your control, OS scheduler could decide one, and then the other even if your implementation does start them concurrently).

Comment: Ok, I got it. Is it technically possible to check if `f1` and `f2` run concurrently, i.e. `f1` starts before `f2` finishes, assuming I implement `f1` and `f2` ?

Comment: You may wrap your functions in other functions that register the Monotonic time of start and end, a check if the start of the second is after the end of the first.

Comment: I am afraid it won't work. Even if `f1` and `f2` are running concurrently OS may decide to execute them sequentially (as it's said before). You probably need to implement the functions _specially_ to make `f2` start before `f1` finishes.

Comment: No, it is not possible, because it would never be deterministic: your program could make every effort to start both functions simultaneously, but it is still up to the system scheduler to decide whether to allow the first one finish completely before the second one starts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest you can do is use some kind of a shared condition that both functions use:

```
def runConcurrently(f1: => Int, f2: => Int): Future[(Int, Int)] = 
   Future(f1) zip Future(f2)

 val sem1 = new Semaphore(0)
 val sem2 = new Semaphore(0)

 def f1 = {
    sem1.release
    sem2.acquire
    1
 }

 def f2 = {
    sem2.release
    sem1.acquire
    2
}

Await.result(runConcurrently(f1, f2), 1 second) shouldBe (1,2)
```

The idea is that neither of the functions can complete before the other one has at least started. So, an attempt to run them sequentially will never finish, and you'll get a timeout.

In particular, this code will fail if you try to run it with a single-threaded execution context.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I am looking for (albeit I don't like the time-out). Now I am wondering when it will _not_ work assuming that I run it a multi threaded execution context on a multitasking OS as Linux or MacOS ?

Comment: The only problem is the timeout since I never know what time it takes to execute these functions.

Comment: I've one more question: can we say that _any_ correct implementation of `runConcurrently` will work for those `f1` and `f2` ?

Answer (score 0):

As said before, this probably wont always work, also is far from being deterministic.
But, it may serve you.

```
final class FunctionMeter[-I, +O](private[this] val underlying: I => O) {
  private[this] var start: Long = _
  private[this] var finish: Long = _

  def getStartTime: Long = start
  def getFinishTime: Long = finish

  def getFun: I => O = input => {
    start = System.nanoTime()
    val output = underlying(input)
    finish = System.nanoTime()
    output
  }
}

def test(f1: Int => Int, f2: Int => Int): Boolean {
  val m1 = new FunctionMeter(f1)
  val m2 = new FunctionMeter(f2)

  runConcurrently(m1.getFunction, m2.getFunction)

  m2.getStartTime < m1.getFinishTime && m1.getStartTime < m2.getFinishTime
}
```

*Anyways, I am with Dima that this is not something you should test.*

Comment: @Dima This only tests that f2 started before f1 finished, in a very broad assumption that the two functions executed in parallel _(which is not the same as concurrent)_ instead of serial. As I myself said, this is far from being a good way to check that `runConcurrently` is really concurrent, but at least it may help in ensure that it is not implemented serially _(something like `(f1(1), f2(2))`)_.

Comment: Of course, there are many problems here, first both functions have to take enough time to execute, so the overhead of starting an asynchronous / parallel computation does not affect the test _(but, if OP want to run two thing at the same time, I believe is "safe" to asume that)_. And as you said, the scheduler may put them in reverse order or made them sequential. And again, I _(the same as you)_ strongly believe this is not the right thing to do. But, I just thought it can help OP in some way of another.

Answer (score -1):

An ugly solution for an ugly problem:

```
object Test extends App {
  def runConcurrently(f1: () => Int, f2: () => Int): (Int, Int) = {
    import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
    val f = Future(f1())
    val g = Future(f2())
    Await.result(f.zip(g), Duration.Inf)
  }

  @volatile var start1: Long = 0
  @volatile var start2: Long = 0
  @volatile var end1: Long = 0
  @volatile var end2: Long = 0

  val f1 : () => Int = {
    case x : Unit => {
      start1 = System.nanoTime()
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      end1 = System.nanoTime()
      1
    }
  }

  val f2 : () => Int = {
    case x : Unit => {
      start2 = System.nanoTime()
      Thread.sleep(1000)
      end2 = System.nanoTime()
      1
    }
  }

  runConcurrently(f1, f2)

  assert(start1 < end2)
  assert(start2 < end1)

}
```

Comment: The asserts in the end do not _have to_ hold. `f` might very well have completed before `g` starts. Or it may not actually start until `g` finishes.

Comment: As @Dima pointed out, my answer is not correct but it, for example, catches the case when `f1` and `f2` run sequentially in reverse order. Your answer doesn't.

Comment: I'm assuming that the goal is to test `runConcurrently` function. So I'm free to choose the input.